# Fab not finding host key

Tags: python, django, ssh, key, fabric

Thank you for taking the time to look at my post.

I have a django site up and running, and I am trying to run a command on the remote (ubuntu) host from my local (windows) computer via fab. I have set the env.key_filename, but every time I run a command I am prompted for the user's password.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Fab Snippet:

```
env.key_filename = "path\to\key.ppk"
env.no_keys = True
env.name = 'testing'
env.user = 'ubuntu'
env.project_name = 'PROJECT'
env.project_root = '/home/%(user)s/venvs/%(name)s/%(project_name)s/' % env
env.host_string = 'myIp'
env.branch = 'master'
env.venv = 'source /home/%(user)s/venvs/%(name)s/bin/activate && ' % env
```

Console:

```
>fab testing install_requirements
[myIp] run: source /home/ubuntu/venvs/testing/bin/activate &&  pip install -r requirements.txt
Password for ubuntu@myIP:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like [Fabric issue #265](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/265). You should use an OpenSSH key, not a .ppk.

Comment: Apparently, PuTTY's [PuTTYgen](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) utility has a “Conversions” menu to help you export the key. I don't use Windows so I can't check.